# Preg_match differences?

Tags: php, mysql, database, regex, preg-match

i want to ask, what is the meaning or difference between these two line?

2. `if( preg_match_all('/\#([א-תÀ-ÿ一-龥а-яa-z0-9\-_]{1,50})/iu', $message, $matches, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER) )` {
3. `if( preg_match_all('/\#([а-яa-z0-9\-_\x{4e00}-\x{9fa5}]{1,50})/iu', $message, $matches, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER) ) {`

and what does the number 3 mean in this line? (Arrow pointing)

```
if( preg_match_all('/\@([a-zA-Z0-9\-_\x{4e00}-\x{9fa5}]{->3,30})/u', $message, $matches, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER) ) {
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll answer the 2nd part of your question:

The `{3,30}` in the regex means `quantifier` for a `min` of `3` and a max of `30` `repetitions`.

- `a*` means zero or more `a`
- `a+` means one or more `a`
- `a?` means zero or one `a`
- `a{1}` means exactly one a same as
  just `a`
- `a{1,}` means one or more a same as
  `a+`
- `a{1,3}` means min of one and max of
  3 `a's`

you can have any complex regex in place of `a`. Example: `[a-zA-Z]{3,30}` would mean at least `3` and at max `30` of any of the alphabets.

Answer (score 0):

Your first regex includes Hebrew and accented Latin characters (and possibly others) that the 2nd regex does not include.

Answer (score 0):

The second expression uses [Unicode syntax](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refunicode.html) to match Unicode characters.

> **\x{FFFF}** where FFFF are 1 to 4 hexadecimal digits
> Perl syntax to match a specific Unicode code point. Can be used inside character classes.
>
> Example:
> \x{E0} matches à  encoded as U+00E0 only.
> \x{A9} matches ©

Thus it tries to match every Unicode character from U+4e00 to U+9fa5 (from [一](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/4e00/index.htm) to
[龥](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/9fa5/index.htm)) whereas the last one is not a valid Unicode character.

---

The first expressions also tries to match these characters (`一-龥`) but they are not expressed in the Unicode syntax (whether or not this opposes a problem I don't know).
In addition (as already mentioned) the first expression matches more characters, namely `א-ת` and `À-ÿ`.

---

The second question [was already very well answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2688875/preg-match-differences/2688919#2688919) by unicornaddict.